# Had 16-bit DOS a memory access limitation of 1 MB? If yes, how?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

I am reading a [OS Development](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev2.html) series, in which there is a statement,

*Due to 16 bit mode limitations, DOS could not access more than 1 MB of memory*

Is this true? If I do 2^16, it gives 64KB, so why the article is saying 1MB limitation?

Comment: There were 16 segments of 64 kB each, for a total of 1 MB.

Comment: See also [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Segmentation) on the segmented architecture that the 8086 used.

Answer (score 1):

Google knows the answer to this.  For example [this Wikipedia article on DOS memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_memory_management) states that:

> The Intel 8088 processor used in the original IBM PC had 20 address lines and so could directly address 1 MB (2<sup>20</sup> bytes) of memory

Other stuff you can find with google will give you lots more detail.